# New Android Places SDK in Android Work Manager

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-places, android-workmanager

To Preface, I'm working in react-native and our app uses a lot of background processes. We've tried a number of react native based solutions like background-fetch, background-geolocation, etc. We've found in testing that the best possible approach for collecting data in background threads is Android's native Work Manager. I've managed to implement a few basic things in Work manager like timestamps and app usage. But now I'm struggling with getting the new Android Places SDK(Google Places is now deprecated) to work in Work Manager. Below is the picture of the error I'm getting.

[Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwZoT.png)

So naturally after getting any error I came here and many of you suggested Async tasks, and creating a handler. Being mostly unfamiliar with Android thread handling I'm not sure how or where to implement such things. So far I've tried calling the Looper.prepare() in onCreate() as well as in my Worker.

This is my Places code

```js
package com.bettertime.betterLocation;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresPermission;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Api;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceRequest;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceResponse;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE;
import static com.bettertime.MainActivity.placesClient;


public class BetterLocation extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<Place.Field> placeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static String TAG = "Location: ";
    public static Map<String, Object> places = new HashMap<>();

    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
    };



    public void findCurrentPlace() {
        places.clear();
        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        findCurrentPlaceWithPermissions();
        }
    }


    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    private void findCurrentPlaceWithPermissions() {


        placeList.add(Place.Field.NAME);
        placeList.add(Place.Field.ADDRESS);
        placeList.add(Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
        placeList.add(Place.Field.TYPES);

        FindCurrentPlaceRequest currentPlaceRequest =
                FindCurrentPlaceRequest.builder(placeList).build();


            if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> currentPlaceTask = placesClient.findCurrentPlace(currentPlaceRequest);

                currentPlaceTask.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FindCurrentPlaceResponse response = task.getResult();
                        assert response != null;
                        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : response.getPlaceLikelihoods()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "findCurrentPlace: "
                                    + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName() + "\n"
                                    + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress() + "\n"
                                    + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng() + "\n"
                                    + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getTypes() + "\n"
                                    + placeLikelihood.getLikelihood());

                            PlaceObj placeObj = new PlaceObj(
                                    placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                                    placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress(),
                                    placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng(),
                                    placeLikelihood.getPlace().getTypes(),
                                    placeLikelihood.getLikelihood());

                            places.put("place", placeObj);
                        }

                    } else {
                        Exception exception = task.getException();
                        if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                            ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                            Log.e(TAG, "findCurrentPlaceWithPermissions: " + apiException.getStatusCode());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
    }



    //////////////////////////
    // Helper methods below //
    //////////////////////////
    private boolean checkPermission(String permission) {
        boolean hasPermission =
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
        if (!hasPermission) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{permission}, 0);
        }
        return hasPermission;
    }

    public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my Work Manager

```js
package com.bettertime.betterWorkManager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;

import com.bettertime.betterLocation.BetterLocation;
import com.bettertime.packages.NativeUsageEvents;
import com.bettertime.timePackage.NativeTime;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import androidx.work.Worker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;

import static com.bettertime.betterLocation.BetterLocation.places;


public class BetterWorkManager extends Worker {

    private static final String TAG = "Work Manager Firing";

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private NativeTime nativeTime = new NativeTime();
    public static Handler mHandler;
    private BetterLocation betterLocation = new BetterLocation();

    public BetterWorkManager(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }




    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Worker.Result doWork() {
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork: fired");


        userStamp();
        return Result.success();
    }


    private void userStamp(){
        Looper.prepare();
         mHandler = new Handler() {
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // process incoming messages here
                betterLocation.findCurrentPlace();
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();

        Log.d(TAG, "places test: " + places.toString());

}
```

I took out some of the unnecessary bits but thats the gist of it. And for good measure here is my main activity.

```js
package com.bettertime;

import android.os.Bundle;


import com.bettertime.betterWorkManager.BetterWorkManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.Places;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.PlacesClient;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import androidx.work.ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy;
import androidx.work.PeriodicWorkRequest;
import androidx.work.WorkManager;



public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    private static final String W_TAG = "Periodic Worker";
    public static PlacesClient placesClient;

    /**
     * Returns the name of the main component registered from JavaScript.
     * This is used to schedule rendering of the component.
     */
    @Override
    protected String getMainComponentName() {
        return "BetterYou";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Places.initialize(getApplicationContext(), "THIS_IS_MY_API_KEY");
        placesClient = Places.createClient(this);
        PeriodicWorkRequest fireUploadBuilder =
                new PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(BetterWorkManager.class, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES).build();
         WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(W_TAG, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, fireUploadBuilder);

    }



}
```

Has anyone out there had success trying to implement Places SDK in Work Manager? Why does Places SDK have to communicate with main UI thread if permissions were already accepted? Any advice is greatly appreciated. I have already looked at the documentation for Looper and AsyncTask but both don't make a lot of sense since I have little context to put them in. If you suggest either please provide context as to where to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much struggle I've figured out a few of my issues. I'll share my code and explain (to the best of my knowledge) what I was doing wrong and how I solved it for those of you who might be trying to doing something similar.

First, my location code!

```js
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresPermission;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.Place;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.model.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceRequest;
import com.google.android.libraries.places.api.net.FindCurrentPlaceResponse;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION;
import static android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE;
import static com.bettertime.MainActivity.placesClient;


public class BetterLocation  {

    private List<Place.Field> placeList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static String TAG = "Location: ";
    public static Map<String, Object> places = new HashMap<>();
    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE
    };

     public void findCurrentPlace(Context context, Activity activity) {

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            findCurrentPlaceWithPermissions(context);
         }
      else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
    }


    @RequiresPermission(allOf = {ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE})
    public void findCurrentPlaceWithPermissions(Context context) {

        placeList.add(Place.Field.NAME);
        placeList.add(Place.Field.ADDRESS);
        placeList.add(Place.Field.LAT_LNG);
        placeList.add(Place.Field.TYPES);

        FindCurrentPlaceRequest currentPlaceRequest =
                FindCurrentPlaceRequest.builder(placeList).build();

        if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            Task<FindCurrentPlaceResponse> currentPlaceTask =
                    placesClient.findCurrentPlace(currentPlaceRequest);

            currentPlaceTask.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    places.clear();
                    FindCurrentPlaceResponse response = task.getResult();
                    assert response != null;
                    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : response.getPlaceLikelihoods()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "findCurrentPlace: "
                                + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName() + "\n"
                                + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress() + "\n"
                                + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng() + "\n"
                                + placeLikelihood.getPlace().getTypes() + "\n"
                                + placeLikelihood.getLikelihood());

                        PlaceObj placeObj = new PlaceObj(
                                placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName(),
                                placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress(),
                                placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng(),
                                placeLikelihood.getPlace().getTypes(),
                                placeLikelihood.getLikelihood());

                        places.put(placeObj.Name, placeObj);
                    }


                } else {
                    Exception exception = task.getException();
                    if (exception instanceof ApiException) {
                        ApiException apiException = (ApiException) exception;
                        Log.e(TAG, "findCurrentPlaceWithPermissions: " + apiException.getStatusCode() + apiException.getLocalizedMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

**Before:** I was using this class as an AppCompatActivity which messed up the context and activity objects I was passing to the methods.

**After:** I changed the method to take in an activity and context. I tested this in my MainActivity passing the MainActivity's context and activity to it and it worked!

Next is my Listenable Worker/Thread Classes!

```js
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.util.Log;
import com.bettertime.MainActivity;
import com.bettertime.betterLocation.BetterLocation;
import com.bettertime.packages.NativeUsageEvents;
import com.bettertime.timePackage.NativeTime;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.SettableFuture;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import androidx.work.ListenableWorker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;
import static com.bettertime.betterLocation.BetterLocation.places;


class LocThread implements Runnable {
    public static LocThread sInstance;
    public static LocThread getInstance(Context context) {
        if (sInstance == null) {
            //Always pass in the Application Context
            sInstance = new LocThread(context.getApplicationContext());
        }

        return sInstance;
    }

    private Context mContext;

    public LocThread(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    private BetterLocation betterLocation = new BetterLocation();
    private Activity activity = new MainActivity().mActivity;
    private String TAG = "LocThread: ";

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Looper.prepare();
            betterLocation.findCurrentPlace(mContext, activity);
            Looper.loop();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "run: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
}

public class FitPlaceWorker extends ListenableWorker {

    private static final String TAG = "FitPlace Worker: ";
    private Thread locThread;


    public FitPlaceWorker(Context context, WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork(){
        SettableFuture<Result> result = SettableFuture.create();
        Log.d(TAG, "doWork - FitPlace fired");

        fitPlaceStamp();
        
        result.set(Result.success());
        return result;
    }


    private void fitPlaceStamp(){

        locThread = new Thread(new LocThread(getApplicationContext()));
        locThread.start();
        //log methods
        Log.d(TAG, "placeData: " + places.toString());
       
    }



}
```

**Before:** Honestly had very little knowledge about android threading so I'm not sure what I was doing in the question example.

**After:** Once I spent some time learning more about threads I figured out how to create my own Thread class. I use a context wrapper to grab the context and I use the MainActivity's activity to pass into my method. The next step was to implement a ListenableWorker instead of the basic Worker which allows you to handle your own threading and to be able to run async tasks. I took out some code to make it a bit more generic so it might be a bit weird but after testing it I was able to log the google places response to the logcat whenever the worker fired off! I do have some little kinks to work out but it seems to work pretty well!

Please let me know if it can be further improved, or if you have a deeper insight and can possibly explain in a better way.

Comment: I am using your code and just wants to find ATMs nearby. But the result has places very close to me. I want the result to contain ATMs quite far from me . Also I want to limit the TYPES to be ATM so that the response is slightly faster.

Answer (score 0):

High-level: You are calling an asynchronous API inside Worker.  Worker is for synchronous background execution.  You may want to look into ListenableWorker, RxWorker, or CoroutineWorker instead: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/threading

Also, I would highly suggest not calling Looper methods on threads given to you by WorkManager.  That's almost always going to result in strange an unexpected problems.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I admit I had little idea where to put that Looper method. '^_^
I'll work on trying to implement a ListenableWorker next!